# How use Pypac for making Get REST call - Python ccode

Tags: python

I am making call for my REST API Get call and it needs proxy authentication(2FA)

So here is my sample code:

```
import requests

from pypac import PACSession, get_pac
from pypac import PACSession
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
pac = get_pac(url='https://abcd.com')
session = PACSession(pac)
session.proxy_auth = HTTPProxyAuth('rkrisha', 'Yubikeycode')

    url =  'http://company.com/sampleapi/v1/logs/errors?startDt=2018-03-26&endDt=2018-03-26'

response = requests.get(url,headers={"Authorization":"Token"})
print(response.text)
```

Getting following Error stack:

```
File "/Users/ynaik/PycharmProjects/Udemy/Python_practice/REST_Get.py", line 12, in <module>
        response = requests.get(url,headers={"Authorization":"Token"})
  File "/Users/ynaik/PycharmProjects/Udemy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ynaik/PycharmProjects/Udemy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ynaik/PycharmProjects/Udemy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/ynaik/PycharmProjects/Udemy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ynaik/PycharmProjects/Udemy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Can someone please take a look and let me know?
How to make 2FA authentication using ubikey and then make a Get API call?

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you facing ??